# Identifying node locations by region

Tags: staking, blockchain

I want to operate stake pool nodes in underserved areas. My cloud provider automatically chooses the cheapest datacenter nearest to me. But I am willing to pay more to deploy to data centers in underdeveloped countries.

How can I identify which regions are saturated and which regions have little or no nearby connectivity?

[The IOHK Shelley node map](https://input-output-hk.github.io/shelley-node-map/), is the best I have found, but it looks hard to interpret. I came away thinking half the nodes are in the ocean.

<sub>Yes, it was...</sub>

Comment: Mobile is bunked. But if there’s something in particular besides boilerplate Good Question stuff I’m not sure what you mean. I want to operate a staking pool where there are few to none, how can I spin up some nodes with in underserved areas?

Comment: Are you talking about staking in under-served locations?  It would also be a good idea to take a look at [ask] for guidance on improving your question.

Comment: I mean there are no links to the docs on mobile.

Comment: Yeah I definitely did a couple of searches. I think participating in the network health is on topic. Thank you for the link

Comment: what was wrong with my question? it has 86% upvote  standing on r/cardano.

Comment: This is not r/Cardano and has a clear mission to provide mostly fact based, enduring, clear and concise answers to Cardano questions.  Take a look at [so] and [se] for the direction this site needs to head in the long run.

Comment: Seems like a waste of time. Just fix it for me. I really don't know what you want.

Comment: Thank you, gRebel. Let's reset. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reddit variety understood the pasta.

[PoolGermany](https://www.reddit.com/r/cardano/comments/o5lptm/is_there_a_map_of_node_locations/h2qptyz?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) says:

> There are some maps:
>
> https://www.adatainment.com/index.php?page=pool_map
>
> https://poolpeek.com/poolpeek.com/poolsearchmap
>
> https://monadpool.com/cardano.html
>
> Enjoy! :)

https://adatools.io/hologram only slightly helpful. But **adatainment** allows one to drill down on to staking pools to see where they are on a political map.

I don't think any of these are exhaustive.